# Pluck specific javascript value from an object based on an array of indexes

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Given a nested object like this:

```
var cars = {
    "bentley": {
        "suppliers": [
            {
            "location": "England",
            "name": "Sheffield Mines"}
        ]
        // ...
    }
};
```

and an array like this `["bentley", "suppliers", "0", "name"]`, is there an existing function that will pluck the deepest element, i.e. `pluck_innards(cars, ['bentley', "suppliers", "0", "name"])` and that returns "Sheffield Mines".

In other words, is there a function (which I will name `deep_pluck`) where

```
deep_pluck(cars, ['bentley', 'suppliers', '0', 'name']) 
         === cars['bentley']['suppliers']['0']['name']
```

It seems to me that this is simple, yet common enough, to have probably been done in one of the Javascript utility libraries such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [lo-dash](http://lodash.com/)/underscore - but I have not seen it.

My thought is something trivial, along the lines of:

```
function deep_pluck(array, identities) {
    var this_id = identities.shift();
    if (identities.length > 0) {
        return deep_pluck(array[this_id], identities);
    }
    return array[this_id];
}
```

Which I have posted [on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmh_ca/VF2ja/).

It would be helpful of course if the function were smart enough to identify when numerical indexes in arrays are needed. I am not sure offhand what other caveats may be a concern.

This is all a fairly long question for something I imagine has already been cleverly solved, but I thought to post this as I would interested in seeing what solutions are out there.

Comment: I'm not sure why this requires a function, or how the function makes things easier in this case..? (Though, as an aside, [a ternary shortens your function a little...](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VF2ja/1/).)

Comment: @DavidThomas: Not knowing the contents of the identities in advance, how else would you do this? I.e. given the array and an array of items to pluck at incrementally increasing depths, is there an alternative?

Comment: *Ah*, I think I misunderstood (I thought you wanted to pass the specific identities to the function, and have the function navigate the object/array).

Comment: I hope it makes sense now :). Let me know if you can think of any edits that would clarify the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you'll have problems with Array indexes if you pass them as number `0`.

Here's alternative version of your function without recursion:

```
function deep_pluck(object, identities) {
    var result = object;
    for(var i = 0; i < identities.length; i++) {
        result = result[identities[i]];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/AmH2w/1/

Comment: This seems better than the unnecessary recursion I was doing. I'll mark this as the answer, because it's a significant improvement over my thoughts. However, an ideal answer I think would be a solution in a pre-existing common and well-maintained library (e.g. lodash/underscore/jquery).

Answer (score 1):

Although not a generic library, it seems that [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) has something of this kind with its [`utils.getPropertyPath`](http://casperjs.org/api.html#utils.getPropertyPath) function.

```
/**
 * Retrieves the value of an Object foreign property using a dot-separated
 * path string.
 *
 * Beware, this function doesn't handle object key names containing a dot.
 *
 * @param  Object  obj   The source object
 * @param  String  path  Dot separated path, eg. "x.y.z"
 */
function getPropertyPath(obj, path) {
    if (!isObject(obj) || !isString(path)) {
        return undefined;
    }
    var value = obj;
    path.split('.').forEach(function(property) {
        if (typeof value === "object" && property in value) {
            value = value[property];
        } else {
            value = undefined;
        }
    });
    return value;
}
```

#### Edit:

I have come across implementations to solve this a couple times since, including:

1. the [getObject](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-getobject-plugin/) plugin by Ben Alman (on [Github](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-getobject)).
2. one I rolled - see [gist](https://gist.github.com/brianmhunt/5512916)

#### Edit (2014)

I would also note the relatively new [`lodash.deep`](https://github.com/marklagendijk/lodash.deep).

Answer (score 1):

dotty.get(obj, pathspec) does it, accepting either an array or a dotted string as the pathspec.

[Dotty](https://github.com/deoxxa/dotty) is open source, and also has an exists method, and a putter.

The methodology is recursion and very similar to your idea, except that dotty includes a test for null/undefined objects so that it doesn't throw exceptions for trying to access an element of something that doesn't exist.

The [dotty.get() source from the docs](http://deoxxa.github.io/dotty/docs/) is posted below:

```
var get = module.exports.get = function get(object, path) {
  if (typeof path === "string") {
    path = path.split(".");
  }

  if (!(path instanceof Array) || path.length === 0) {
    return;
  }

  path = path.slice();

  var key = path.shift();

  if (typeof object !== "object" || object === null) {
    return;
  }

  if (path.length === 0) {
    return object[key];
  }

  if (path.length) {
    return get(object[key], path);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short ES6 implementation using `reduce`:

```
function get(obj, keyPath) {
    return keyPath
        .split(".")
        .reduce((prev, curr) => prev[curr], obj);
}
```

Usage:

```
get(cars, "bentley.suppliers.0.name") // -> "Sheffield Mines"
```