# How to deep check for "null" or "undefined" with JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, null, undefined

In a Node.JS project, let's say I have a response from an API or any other object with a structure like

```
{
  data: {
    info: {
      user: {
        name: "Hercules",
        password: "Iamthegreatest!"
        email: "hercules@olymp.gr"
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

Accessing the members of the object is pretty easy. However, checking the existence before accessing any value gets PITA.

I can assume that data is always present. Info, user, name, password and email may be present or may not. There can be a valid info object without an user and there can be a valid user without an email address.

This leads to code like

```
if (data && data.info && data.info.user && data.info.user.email) {
  var email = data.info.user.email;
}
```

Only checking for

```
if (data.info.user.email)
  // do something
}
```

Throws an error if any of the objects do not exist.

Is there a shorter way to deep check the existence of structures like this?

Comment: C# 6 is introducing the [?.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator.aspx) operator.  You can do `var email = data?.info?.user?.email;`  Maybe JS will follow.  I think Groovy was the 1st implementation.

Comment: @RichardSchneider, and maybe JS won't... ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pluck specific javascript value from an object based on an array of indexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785377/pluck-specific-javascript-value-from-an-object-based-on-an-array-of-indexes)

Comment: [Dotty](https://www.npmjs.org/package/dotty) should be useful here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the console in your project directory, `npm install dotty`

Then at the top of your code, import dotty with:  `var dotty = require('dotty')`

then if `obj` is the object posted above, you can call

`dotty.exists(obj, "data.info.user.email")`

and it will yield `true` or `false` instead of throwing an error.

See https://www.npmjs.org/package/dotty

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, since a lot of developers already use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/), is Lodash's  [`get()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#get) method:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

let data = {
  info: {
    user: {
      email: 'user.email@example.com'
    }
  }
};

_.get(data, 'info.user.email');
// => 'user.email@example.com'
```

A nice thing about `get()` is that it supports a default value for cases where the resolved value is `undefined`:

```
_.get(data, 'info.user.emailAddress', 'default.email@example.com');
// => 'default.email@example.com'
```